# If SQL Server ODBC driver times out, will it show as a long running query on the database side?

Tags: sql-server, timeout, odbc

I have an application which uses a SQL Server ODBC driver to connect to a database. The driver is set to timeout after 5 seconds.

We have received timeouts on some insert statements, however the long running queries on the database are not picking up these timeouts.

If the driver is timing out the connection before the insert is complete, should the database be displaying these in the long running queries (in this case set to log any >2000 ms)? I notice that the ones that do appear say "Query Completed in x seconds", but there's nothing about incomplete queries.

Just wanted to rule this out before digging further into why they might be missing from the results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing some tests I found it doesn't record as a long running query unless the query is completed. All ODBC Driver timeouts returned no results in the long running queries.